# How can one use TensorFlow.js tf.data.generator for remote data sources since generators can't use callbacks

Tags: javascript, generator, tensorflow.js

When introducing the tf.data.Dataset API, the [Deep Learning with JavaScript book](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-javascript) says:

> Large applications require technology for accessing data from a remote source, piece by piece, on demand.

But the documentation I've read about generators says a generator can't produce values via callbacks. But how else can one access remote sources? I don't see how one can use [tf.data.generator](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.generator) in such cases. [MDN documentation on yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) states:

> yield can only be called directly from the generator function that contains it. It can't be called from nested functions or from callbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an `async` function (or a function returning a Promise) to the generator. It is then okay to use `await` inside the function (even inside a loop) to handle any asynchronous tasks.

**Code Sample**

```js
const dataset = tf.data.generator(async function* () {
    const dataToDownload = await fetch(/* ... */);
    while (/* ... */) {
        const moreData = await fetch(/* ... */);
        yield otherData;
    }
});
```

This example uses [`node-fetch`](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch), of course any other method of downloading data also works fine.

#### Async Generators

Regarding the MDN documentation, generators can be defined as `async`, but this changes the way they work. Instead of returning the value right away, they will return a Promise that you have to await for. So, instead of calling `iterator.next()`, you have to call `await iterator.next()` to read the value.

**Code Sample**

```js
async function* foo(index) {
  while (true) {
    yield index++;
  }
}

(async () => {
  const iterator = foo(0);
  console.log((await iterator.next()).value); // 0
  console.log((await iterator.next()).value); // 1
})();
```

Luckily, Tensorflow.js is able to handle `async` functions/Promises in generators.

Comment: It's strange why in typescript tfjs doesn't expect see functions with type of `AsyncGenerator<T>` as you provided. It's expects only `Iterator<T>| Promise<Iterator<T>>`

Comment: i get a type error with this approach. any idea how to conform typescript? `Type 'Promise<IteratorResult<never, void>>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<TensorContainer, any>'.ts(2345)`